# Selecionar diferentes valores mediante un radiobutton

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp, prepared-statements

Buenas tardes tengo un problema,
tengo una tabla que se llena de informacion de mi base de datos, el problema es que por cada fila tengo un radiobutton con las opciones si y no para confirmar dicha informacion,

```
 <div class="container">
            <br><div class="alert alert-info" role="alert"><center>LISTADO DE ESTUDIANTES</center></div>
            <h6>*REGISTRO DEL ID O CEDULA DE LOS ESTUDIANTES QUE ASISTIERON ALA TUTORIA<span class="label label-default"></span></h6>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Input" class="col-sm-6 control-label">ID O CEDULA DELOS ESTUDIANTES</label><br>
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td>PIDM</td>
                            <td>ID</td>
                            <td>ESTUDIANTES</td>
                            <td>EMAIL</td>
                            <td>CÉDULA</td>
                            <td>PRESENTES</td>
                        <tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <%   PreparedStatement st;
                            ResultSet ts;
                            st = co.prepareStatement("select * from uztasistentes where codigo_uztplanif ='" + codr + "'  and codigo_uzgtformularios =3");
                            ts = st.executeQuery();
                            //      Formularios_Connection con = F
                            while (ts.next()) {
                        %> 
                        <tr>
                            <td class="text-center"><%= ts.getInt("SPRIDEN_PIDM")%> </td>
                            <td class="text-center"><%= ts.getString("UZTASISTENTES_ID")%> </td>
                            <td class="text-center"><%= ts.getString("UZTASISTENTES_ESTUDIANTE")%> </td>
                            <td class="text-center"><%= ts.getString("UZTASISTENTES_EMAIL")%> </td>
                            <td class="text-center"><%= ts.getString("UZTASISTENTES_CEDULA")%> </td>
                            <td <label class="radio-inline">
                                    <input type="radio" name="optradio">SI
                                </label>
                                <label class="radio-inline">
                                    <input type="radio" name="optradio">NO
                                </label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    <% }
                        ts.close();
                    %> 
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

el problema es que  si tengo 20 filas con datos, solo me deja seleccionar la respuesta de una sola fila, por ejemplo seleciono si en la fila 1, voy a la fila 2 selecciono no y automaticamente se borra la seleccion que hice en la fila 1.
Algun consejo para poder corregir este error.
estaria muy agradecido

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ACTUALIZADO:**

Los elementos de tipo `input type="radio"` solo aceptan 1 valor marcado entre todos los que compartan su mismo atributo `name`.

Para que te permita marcar un solo valor por cada fila el atributo `name` de los `radios` deberían crearse con diferentes valores.

Por ejemplo en la primera fila podría ser:

```
<td>
  <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="optradio-1 value="SI">SI
  </label>
  <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="optradio-1" value="NO" checked>NO
  </label>
</td>
```

Y las demás filas deberían irse generando con: `name="optradio-2"`, `name="optradio-3"` etc

O en tu caso podrías usar su Id

```
name="optradio-<%= ts.getString("UZTASISTENTES_ID")%>"
```

Por otro lado te recomiendo usar JSTL en lugar de scriptlet, es más limpio y legíble.

Para recibir los datos de tu form en un servlet tendrías que iterarlos:

```
Enumeration enumeration = request.getParameterNames();

while(enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
  String parameterName = enumeration.nextElement();
  /**
  * aquí tendrías el valor de cada parámetro recibido en el request
  * tocaría asignarlo a un tipo de dato(Array, List) y luego procesarlo
  */
  request.getParameter(parameterName);
}
```

Comment: amigo otra consulta si me funcionó esta linea:                             
 name="optradio-<%= ts.getString("UZTASISTENTES_ID")%>"                                ahora tengo otra duda como, como todo esto esta en un form, como recibiria los valores que elegí, como seria el nombre final del name ejemplo:                      porque pongo esto y sale nulo los valores string radio = request.getParameter("optradio");

Comment: y en cambio este da error String radio = request.getParameter("optradio-<%= ts.getString("UZTASISTENTES_ID")%>");